# Isomorphism of quotient rings: sending generator of one ideal to another

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be some algebraically closed field. Let $R=k[x,y]$ let $R'=k[s,t]$. I want to show that $R/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is isomorphic as a ring to $R'/(st-1)$. In some sense this is obvious as we can send $t\mapsto x+iy$ and $s\mapsto x-iy$. Then $st-1$ is send to $x^2+y^2-1$ and everything should work out nicely.

I am not sure how to check that everything works out nicely though. To check that everything works out nicely in this specific case seems very awkward. Surely there must be a more abstract statement that is easier to prove.
Is there some theorem stating if $f:R \rightarrow R'$ sends the generator of an ideal $I\subset R$ to the generator of an ideal $I'\subset R'$ then $R/I$ is isomorphic to $R'/I'$.

Comment: I don't know if anyone's written down that theorem, but its proof is straightforward (as long as $f$ is an isomorphism), and generalises to ideals with more than one generator.

Comment: If such an $f$ is an isomorphism, then it is a surjection. Then $f$ composted with the quotient map is a surjection to $R'/I'$. Its not obvious to me that something can't go wrong with the kernel of this map. For example something like $x\mapsto x^2$ (obviously this isn't an isomorphism) but something does go wrong with the kernels.

Comment: @MarkMurray Following [Angina Seng](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/angina-seng), a proof of the *theorem* as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to practice my algebra following [Angina Seng](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/angina-seng) comment.

So let's suppose that $f : R \to R^\prime$ is a ring isomorphism. The quotient map $\bar f$is a surjective ring homomorphism between $R$ and $R^\prime / I^\prime$. We'll be done if we prove that $\ker \bar f = I$ according to [first ring homomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Rings).

By hypothesis, $I$ is generated by a family of elements $\mathcal I=\{i_j \mid j \in J\}$ and $I^\prime$ is generated by $\mathcal I^\prime = \{f(i_j) \mid j \in J\}$.

$x \in \ker \bar f$ means $f(x) \in I^\prime$ i.e. that it exists $j_1, \dots, j_n \in J$ and $r_1^\prime, \dots, r_n\prime \in R^\prime$ such that

$$f(x) = \sum_k r_k^\prime f(i_{j_k})$$ which is equivalent as $f$ is an isomorphism to
$$f(x) = f(\sum_k f^{-1}(r_k^\prime) i_{j_k})$$ and to $x = \sum_k f^{-1}(r_k^\prime) i_{j_k}$, proving that $x \in I$ as desired.